How to create a ZIP file from byte array using Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream?
I need to save a byte array as a compressed ZIP file. As MemoryStream can grow large and cause out-of-memory exceptions on our shared Azure server instances, I'm using Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, which has saved me from out-of-memory exceptions in a few other cases.
However, it does not want to work with ZipArchive nicely.
The first attempt with a simple test example causes unfinalized archive that cannot be opened:
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test string");

byte[] compressedBytes = default;

var manager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
using var originalStream = manager.GetStream("Raw", data);
using var compressedStream = manager.GetStream("Compressed");
using var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false);

var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("test.txt");
using var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open();
originalStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);

// the following does not help, the archive is still corrupt
zipEntryStream.Flush();
zipEntryStream.Close();

compressedBytes = compressedStream.ToArray();

// the result - File cannot be opened: "Unexpected end of archive"
// BTW, I know this is not a good way to return bytes from a controller method; using just for testing the bytes directly
return File(compressedBytes, "application/zip", "test.zip");


It seems ZipArchive needs to be disposed to finalize the archive. So I tried this next:

using var originalStream = manager.GetStream("Raw", data);
using var compressedStream = manager.GetStream("Compressed");

// scoped `using` statement here
// to ensure the zip archive gets disposed early enough,
// otherwise it's not finalized; and Flush + Close does not help
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
{
    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("test.txt");
    using var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open();
    originalStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
}
// Exception: Cannot access a disposed object.:(
compressedBytes = compressedStream.ToArray();


This time the archive is finalized but bytes cannot be retrieved because ZipArchive has disposed the underlying RecyclableMemoryStream.
Only the classic approach with MemoryStream works fine:
var manager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
using var originalStream = manager.GetStream("Raw", data);
using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
// scoped `using` statement here
// to ensure the zip archive gets disposed early enough,
// otherwise it's not finalized; and Flush + Close does not help
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
{
    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("test.txt");
    using var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open();
    originalStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
}

compressedBytes = compressedStream.ToArray();


So, this seems to be one of those rare cases when RecyclableMemoryStream does not work well as a drop-in replacement for MemoryStream.
Is there any way to force ZipArchive to finalize the zip without disposing the underlying stream?
Or should I use a different tool instead of ZipArchive?

new ZipArchive(compressedStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false) -- change that false to true, and ZipArchive won't dispose the stream when it's disposed.

And yes, MemoryStream has special behaviour to allow ToArray to be called even after it's been disposed, precisely because of use-cases like this.

How about using a FileStream and a temp file instead?

@canton7 Thank you, indeed, that was so simple. Silly me. I assumed that leaveOpen flag would also not finalize it as if I wanted to add more files to the archive. I interpreted it wrong. So ZipArchive has the archive finalization coupled with its own disposal and not with the stream's disposal.

If you are having trouble with out-of-memory exceptions, you should avoid ToArray() as explained in the usage guidelines: Most applications should not call ToArray and should avoid calling GetBuffer if possible. Instead, use GetReadOnlySequence for reading...

@dbc  Thank you for reminding this; yes, I will make sure I use .GetReadOnlySequence()  and replace all uses of byte[] with ReadOnlySequence<byte>.
